# Is it possible to calculate imaginary exponents without trig functions?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

If I have a problem such as $2^i$, I would use the rules:

$$
e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i\sin{x} \\
b^n = e^{n\ln{b}}
$$

Applying this to the example $2^i$, I would let $x=\ln{2}$:
$$
e^{i\ln{2}} = \cos{(\ln{2})} + i\sin{(\ln{2})} = 0.769238901364+0.638961276314i
$$
The calculator agrees with my result. However, is it possible to calculate these imaginary exponents without the use of sine and cosine?

Comment: How about using the Taylor series for $e^z$ to evaluate $e^{i \log 2}$?

Comment: I mean, call $\phi$ the magical box that tells you $x\mapsto x^i$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$ (let's say we solved any issue of definition). Then $$\cos(x)=\frac12\phi(x)+\frac12\overline{\phi(x)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed with either Taylor's theorem or Binomial expansion theorem.

Taylor's theorem:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\tag{$n!=1\times2\times3\times\dots\times n,0!=1$}$$

Or, for general bases,

$$a^x=e^{x\ln(a)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{[x\ln(a)]^n}{n!}$$

For example,

$$e^i=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{i^n}{n!}=1+i-\frac12-\frac i6+\frac1{24}+\frac i{120}-\dots$$

Doesn't give the exact answer with trig functions, but you can calculate it to any degree of accuracy.

---

To use binomial expansion theorem, assume $1^i=1$.

General binomial expansion theorem is given as

$$(a+b)^n=\frac1{0!}a^n+\frac n{1!}a^{n-1}b+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}a^{n-2}b^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}a^{n-3}b^3+\dots+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k)}{k!}a^{n-k-1}b^{k+1}+\dots$$

For example,

$$2^i=(1+1)^i=1+i+\frac{i(i-1)}2+\frac{i(i-1)(i-2)}6+\dots$$

That'll also get you to the answer you want.

In general,

$$a^i=[(a-1)+1]^i=\dots$$

Note binomial expansion will allow you to deal with $i^i$, whereas Taylor's theorem won't (at least not easily).

Comment: I didn't know it converged so quickly. After mere 8 terms of the taylor series, I already got ~5 decimal points correct. Is this only because 2 is a small number? Would a larger base converge more slowly?

Comment: @TheBro21 I am unsure about the convergence, but I'm glad it works.  (I think it converges decently fast)  I'd personally stick to the taylor series as much as possible, but you can resort to the binomial expansion if the base is complex.

Comment: @TheBro21 Also note that there is an alternating nature, so each term cancels a bit with other terms, providing faster convergence.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$:
>
> $$z=\Re[z]+\Im[z]i=|z|e^{\arg(z)i}=|z|\cos(\arg(z))+|z|\sin(\arg(z))i$$
>
> Where $|z|=\sqrt{\Re^2[z]+\Im^2[z]}$ and $\arg(z)$ is the complex argument.

---

So, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$:

$$x^z=x^{|z|e^{\arg(z)i}}=x^{|z|\cos(\arg(z))+|z|\sin(\arg(z))i}=$$
$$x^{|z|\cos(\arg(z))}\cdot x^{|z|\sin(\arg(z))i}=x^{|z|\cos(\arg(z))}\cdot e^{\ln\left(x^{|z|\sin(\arg(z))i}\right)}=$$
$$x^{|z|\cos(\arg(z))}\cdot e^{|z|\sin(\arg(z))\ln(x)i}=$$
$$x^{|z|\cos(\arg(z))}\cdot\left(\cos(|z|\sin(\arg(z))\ln(x))+\sin(|z|\sin(\arg(z))\ln(x))i\right)$$

Comment: The op asks us to avoid trig functions...  But good to point out how to calculate for $z\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I saw your answer, when I was reading mostly the same, so I tought I make my answer more like the OP work, but generalize it.